# How to specify dependency on external C library in .cabal?

Tags: windows, haskell, packaging, cabal, pkg-config

I maintain a library with FFI bindings on Hackage. So my Haskell library depends on the corresponding C library and its header files. Now I specify the external dependency in the `.cabal` file like this:

```
PkgConfig-Depends:
      libfoo >= 1.2
```

And it works well for me in Linux. However, I have a user of the library who reports, that installing `pkg-config` on Windows is rather cumbersome, and instead he prefers

```
Includes:
      foo.h
Extra-libraries:
      foo
```

I'd like my library to be as easy to build as possible, and don't want to force build dependencies which are not strictly required. However, I see that [Cabal manual](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/release/cabal-latest/doc/users-guide/authors.html) suggests to use `PkgConfig-Depends`.

My questions:

- Which way I should prefer for cross-platform packages?
- Is it possible to write a `.cabal` file in such a way, that it can work with `pkg-config` and without?
- And, by the way, is `pkg-config` included in the Haskell platform (I don't have a Windows machine to check right now)?

Comment: pkg-config is not included with the Platform on Windows (2010.2.0.0).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The pkg-config method is preferable because pkg-config knows where to find include and library files, which may be in nonstandard locations on some systems.

You can write the .cabal file to use both methods.  Using a flag, as shown here, has the advantage that Cabal will automatically try the other flag value if the default fails.  (Below example is not tested)

```
Flag UsePkgConfig
  Description: Use pkg-config to check for library dependences
  Default: True

Executable hax
  if flag(UsePkgConfig)
    PkgConfig-Depends: libfoo >= 1.2
  else
    Includes: foo.h
    Extra-libraries: foo
```

Comment: Thank you. I chose this approach with a flag, alas I preferred `NoPkgConfig` flag instead, because `cabal configure -fNoPkgConfig` is more readable than `cabal configure -f-UsePkgConfig`. This approach works well on Linux (either with and without `pkg-config` installed). I'll report what's the Windows user feedback is later.

Answer (score 6):

`pkg-config` is not included in the Haskell Platform, nor could I imagine that it ever would be.

Usually I will use `includes/Extra-libraries` if they're relatively simple.  But for complex packages that may have a lot of included libraries, such as gtk, it's much nicer to use pkg-config when available.

It is possible to write a .cabal file that will work with and without specific fields.  Try this:

```
if os(windows)
  Includes:
      foo.h
  Extra-libraries:
      foo
else
  PkgConfig-Depends:
      libfoo >= 1.2
```

Also note that `.cabal` can run a configure script, which can help in some situations but isn't very windows-friendly.

Comment: Thank you. I considered to do something like this, but probably the solution proposed by @Heatsink is more flexible. I'll try that one first.

Comment: @jetxee - it's true that flags can be more flexible, but they can cause problems too.  Cabal seems to want to recompile already-installed packages when a new package is built with a different set of flags, which can put your package db into an inconsistent state.  I may be biased because I've just had to fix my package db though.