# cabal FFI dependency

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi, conio

I am making a small Haskell game in Windows, where I would like to respond each time the user presses a key. Because `getChar` [behaves strangely](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2189) on Windows, I use FFI to get access to `getch` in `conio.h`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983974/haskell-read-input-character-from-console-immediately-not-after-newline). The relevant code is:

```
foreign import ccall unsafe "conio.h getch" c_getch :: IO CInt
```

This works fine, when I run it in ghci, or compile it with ghc. I also want to try making a cabal package out of it, so extending from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959802/how-to-specify-dependency-on-external-c-library-in-cabal) question, I include the following in my cabal file:

```
...
executable noughts
  Includes:          conio.h
  Extra-libraries    conio
...
```

But when I run `cabal configure`, it tells me:

```
cabal: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing C library: conio
```

It makes sense, because in my haskell platform directory, under `...\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\mingw` there is a `conio.h` file under the `include` directory, but no other `conio` file to provide the object code.

Am I doing this the right way, and if so, how can I find out which library to include in my cabal file?

Comment: There are various libraries that provide the conio functions. Have you tried `Extra-Libraries: crtdll` or `Extra-Libraries: msvcrt`? By the way, according to MSDN, you should use `_getch` instead of `getch`, but the header file might do that for you.

Comment: Note that this only affects ghc/ghci in Windows, and the solution code doesn't work in WinHugs in particular, so you need it to only compile with this when it's specifically Windows/ghc.

Comment: @Tinctorius I have just tried `Extra-libraries: msvcrt` and `Extra-libraries: crtdll` alone and in combination. It didn't change the output of `cabal build`. I found `msvcrt.lib` and `crtdll.c` under my visual studio installation, and copied them to my folder, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Tinctorius In ghci and compiling with ghc, it seems to work with both `getch` and `_getch`. `conio.h` includes `getch` `#ifndef _NO_OLDNAMES`, so I guess that's not defined for me. But thanks, changed to `_getch`.

Comment: @Boris: if you say `Extra-Libraries: NAME`, Cabal should be looking for `...\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\mingw\lib\libNAME.a`. I have `libcrtdll.a` in that directory, so a dependency on `crtdll` works fine for me. Have you tried supplying the `--extra-lib-dirs` parameter to `cabal`, pointing to that directory?

Comment: @Tinctorius: I now have `Extra-libraries: crtdll` in my cabal file. I have the file `libcrtdll.a` under `...\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\mingw\lib`, and I have configured cabal with the `extra-lib-dirs="(Path to lib dir)"` flag. I now get the error: `parse error on input 'import`, so it's different. B.t.w., I thought cabal would include the `lib` folder by default?

Comment: @Tinctorius: I found out how to solve the `parse error on input 'import'` that I got. I just needed `extensions: ForeignFunctionInterface` in my cabal file. Now it works, even without the `--extra-lib-dirs` flag, it seems cabal looks in the `...\mingw\lib` folder automatically. If you write up your comments as an answer, I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, there is not always a one-to-one mapping between C header files and libraries. In this case, the functions declared in `conio.h` can be found in various runtime libraries, such as `crtdll` (deprecated) or `msvcrt` (preferred, I guess).

With the Haskell Platform on Windows, Cabal will look for these libraries in `.\mingw\lib` (under your Haskell Platform directory): if you ask for `msvcrt`, it will look for `.\mingw\lib\libmsvcrt.a`. This specific library should already be shipped with your Haskell Platform. (If you want to point to other directories with `lib*.a` files, you can use Cabal's `--extra-lib-dirs` option.)

A tiny example of this would be as follows; this is `Main.hs`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
import Foreign.C.Types
foreign import ccall unsafe "conio.h _putch" c_putch :: CInt -> IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    c_putch . toEnum . fromEnum $ '!'
    c_putch . toEnum . fromEnum $ '\n'
```

And this would be `something-awesome.cabal`:

```
name:                something-awesome
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.8

executable yay
  main-is:             Main.hs
  build-depends:       base ==4.5.*

  includes:            conio.h
  extra-libraries:     msvcrt
```

This should work fine:

```
c:\tmp\something-awesome> dir /B
Main.hs
something-awesome.cabal

c:\tmp\something-awesome> cabal configure
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring something-awesome-0.1.0.0...

c:\tmp\something-awesome> cabal build
Building something-awesome-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'yay' for something-awesome-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, dist\build\yay\yay-tmp\Main.o )
Linking dist\build\yay\yay.exe ...

c:\tmp\something-awesome> dist\build\yay\yay.exe
!
```

Comment: For future reference, is there somewhere I can look up which library provides a function? How did you find out that `_getch` is provided by msvcrt and crtdll, and that the latter is deprecated? Light googling didn't reveal anything.

Comment: MSDN is (a bad attempt at) the canonical Windows development manual, which usually gives the header file and library to use for a given function (you can search it with Google's `site:` operator). The article on [_getch and friends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) only mentions that "all versions of the C run-time libraries" support it. After finding `libcrtdll.a` and `libmsvcrt.a` in my `lib` directory (CRT = C run-time), I then searched Google for the difference between `crtdll` and `msvcrt`, and figured out the former is a relic from the Windows 95 era.

Comment: @Thanks, nice detective work. Yeah, MSDN seems not exactly designed to lead you straight to the information you need :)

Comment: I had the same issue with GHCJS, with "foreign import javascript" (reflex-platform) and solved now. Thanks!